# Laravel 5 eloquent - where (status = 1 or status = 2)

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have a problem using orWhere in eloquent.

I have a team, and this team has som profiles. I want to get all the profiles which have the status = 1 or status = 2. But I cant get it to work.

My code is like this:

```
$profile = $this->team->profiles->where('status', 1)->find($id);
```

Thanks:-)

Comment: Why even use a where for the status if you call `find($id)` afterwards? (which should only match one record on its own)

Comment: Because I dont want people to change the url to ex. profile/2 and then get the profile, if he dosent have the status 1 or 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling `where()` on the result of the relationship (which I assume is a collection) you should call it on the relationship object itself, which you can get by calling the function that defines this relation:

```
$profile = $this->team->profiles()->whereIn('status', [1,2])->find($id)
```

I also suggest to use `whereIn` instead of two `where`s...

Answer (score 4):

You can use, the Where In function with An Array

```
$profile = $this->team->profiles->whereIn('status', [1, 2])->get();
```